# How can I fit these isometric tiles into a TileMap?

Tags: unity, 2d, isometric

I have downloaded this 2d isometric tileset : https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/environments/cute-isometric-town-starter-pack-134286

But when I tried to create a map in Unity, I have this :

[image]

But in the tool "Tiled", I was able to do this :

[image]

But to do this in Tiled, I had to set tile size to 1024x720px.

How can I do the same thing in Unity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the width/height ratio of your tiles doesn't match that of your Grid component.

Go to [the Grid component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Grid.html) of your tilemap and set the cell size accordingly. When your tiles are 1024 x 720, then your cell size ratio also needs to have the same ratio. Setting those to 1024 and 720 will probably be far too big, because now a single tile is 1024 Unity units across. You certainly *could* work like that, but it is probably a bit unwieldy. But you can also set those to a much lower value as long as the ratio stays the same. For example 64 : 45 or 1 : 0.703125.

After you did that, you will probably notice that your tiles are either too small or too large to fill a cell properly. You can fix that by going to the import setting of the tileset image and adjust the "pixels per unit" setting to 1024 divided by the X-size of your grid.

Comment: Thank you, It solved the problem.